# How do I stop my blog page from displaying same content as home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I am trying to have a separate page to display my posts and ensure the home page remains as the front page.

I have gone to settings > reading and set the front page as home and the posts page as blog. But when I visit url/blog, it displays same contents as the home page rather than my blog posts.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Could this be a problem?

Comment: Maybe you are calling the loop from front-page.php block. Check it in wp-content/themes/<ur active theme>/front-page.php

Comment: Thanks Apeiron. Checking that now

Comment: If your theme doesnt contain front-page.php show me the list of files below wp-content/themes/<urtheme>/  . You can do it with ls in linux. And check this also: https://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Comment: In the active theme, I can't see the front-page.php but I can see index.php, single.php and page.php. Which of these do I need to check out?

Comment: Copy your page.php to a new file called front-page.php. Now you will override index.php and home.php (if exists). https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Comment: I found the front-page.php file but it's empty. Let me copy the page.php to it and see how it pans out.

Comment: I have copied page.php to front-page.php as advised bu now, the home page contents no longer appear on blog page but the blog page is empty.

Comment: Okey I leave you a link, because I have to go. https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: The error message that appears on the blog page after deactivating the plugins implies the error could be caused by the layerslider plugin.

/home/essalvpz/public_html/wp-content/themes/essaywritingteam/index.php on line 4"

I just visited the server and checked out the line 4 of the index.php and this is what it looks like:

<?php layerslider(1) ?>

Could there be an issue with this code that requires fixing or I need to delete the layerslider plugin altogether?